# showing "Welcome" popup after woocommerce user registration

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, registration

I have a popup for new users but I don't know how can I call it. Which hook should I use to show the popup?

```
      <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    jQuery( window ).load(function() {
                        jQuery('.newsletterpopup').show();
                        jQuery('.popupshadow').show();
                    }); 
            });
             </script>
```

This code shows welcome popup

Comment: did you try... `user_register` hook? something like: `add_action( 'user_register', 'myfunction', 10, 1 );`

Comment: yes, but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the **user_register** hook in WordPress and display your welcome popup in the callback function

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myfunction', 10, 1 );

function myfunction( $user_id ) {

// Your code here

}
```

Comment: I tried that but did not work. After registration, its redirecting to home page. so the popup have to shown in home page. Also the register page by woocommerce

Comment: Did you try adding  some js jQuery script for popup in the callback function ? You can use e.perventDefault()  to stop  the redirection , that way you won't have to add the popup in your home page but rather the callback function would do that for you.

Comment: the popup have to shown after register redirection, this is what is required of me.